# flutter: navigating to homePage shows error

Tags: flutter

i'm using this code to navigate to MyHomepage() when app runs but when app opens flutter terminal shows me this error , i have no idea about reason behind it, any help?

```html
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Products2()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Cart()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Wishe()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'project1',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.white,
          accentColor: color1,
        ),
       
        home: MyHomePage(),
        routes: {
          DetailPage.routeName: (ctx) => DetailPage(),
          CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
          WishList.routeName: (ctx) => WishList(),
          KDetailPage.routeName: (ctx) => KDetailPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error:

sLayout': is not true.
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1704 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1704 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1704 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (26406): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed

Comment: Try changing `home` to `initialRoute` and u need to add `MyHomePage()` in the `routes`

Comment: yes i did it to initial route, but when i add the class my app it ruined every thing and screen comes white

Comment: Did u add MyBHomePage as one of the routes?

Comment: i did void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}
and then i Called MyAPP() when one of the button pressed but same issue :/

Comment: Can u post ur code on https://codepen.io/flutter